# How to find a class instance name in other class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, reflection

Imagine a situation that we have two classes like these:

```
class MyClass {
    func printInstanceName() {
        print(what?);
    }
}

class User {
    var firstObject: MyClass!
    var secondObject: MyClass!
}
```

I will instantiate an object of class User like this:

```
let user = User();
user.firstObject = MyClass()
user.secondObject = MyClass()
```

How should i implement the `printInstanceName` that the output of code below

```
user.firstObject.printInstanceName()
user.secondObject.printInstanceName()
```

be

```
firstObject
secondObject
```

The purpose of doing this is, i want to know from which instance of `MyClass` in `User`, `printInstanceName` is called!

Comment: What exactly would you do with this, if it were possible?

Comment: If you want to print a description of the instance then make the class conform to `CustomStringConvertible`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica it is important for me because i have multiple field of type MyClass in my User class and i want to determine that 'printInstanceName' is called from which field?

Comment: "i want to determine that 'printInstanceName' is called from which field" And what would you do with *that* if it existed?

Comment: i want to perform different action base on which instance this method in called from

Comment: Then you shouldn't rely on some name but rather which property is being used, maybe by using willSet or didSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get variable name only in this way

```
class MyClass {
    func printInstanceNameIn(user: User) {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: user)
        for (label, value) in mirror.children {
            if let value = value as? MyClass, value === self {
                print(label!)
            }
        }
    }
}

class User {
    var firstObject: MyClass!
    var secondObject: MyClass!
}

let u = User()
u.firstObject = MyClass()
u.secondObject = MyClass()
u.firstObject.printInstanceNameIn(user: u)
```

Comment: So there is no way that ```printInstanceName``` be in ```MyClass``` not in ```User```?

Answer (score 0):

You cant get property name from MyClass, only from User.

```
class MyClass { }

class User {
    var myObject: MyClass!
    
    func printInstanceName() {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for (label, value) in mirror.children {
            if type(of: value) == Optional<MyClass>.self {
                print(label!)
            }
        }
    }
}

let u = User()
u.printInstanceName()
```

Comment: it just printed "MyClass". i don't want to print class name. i want to print MyClass object name in "User" class. Actually i want "myObject" to be printed!

Comment: You cant get it in that way like you mentioned. Will create another answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Use **`String(describing: type(of: self))`** to print the class name.

```
class MyClass {
    func printInstanceName() {
        print(String(describing: type(of: self)))
    }
}
```

Don't use *force-unwrapped* variables unnecessarily. You can create an `init(myObject:)` instead.

```
class User {
    var myObject: MyClass
    
    init(myObject: MyClass) {
        self.myObject = myObject
    }
}
```

Create `User` instance like,

```
let user = User(myObject: MyClass())
user.myObject.printInstanceName()
```

Comment: it just printed "MyClass". i don't want to print class name. i want to print MyClass object name in "User" class. Actually i want "myObject" to be printed!

Comment: What do you mean by myObject name? That's just a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you're exactly looking for but it might helps:

```
    for child in Mirror(reflecting: user).children {
    print(child.label)
}
```